# FPDF: How to limit the fetch data so footer will not add to next page

Tags: php, pdf, footer, fpdf

How can I add a limitation on the output so that the footer will not go to next page?

```
class myPDF extends FPDF{

    function header(){
        $dates = new DateTime();
        $date2 = $dates->format('Y');
        $date=$_POST['month'];
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
        $this->Cell(189,5,'ABSTRACT OF COMMUNITY TAX CERTIFICATES',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Times','',13);
        $this->Cell(189,10,'For the month of '.$date.' '.$date2,0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
    function headerTable(){
        $this->SetTextColor(136,0,0);
        $this->SetFont('Times','B',10);
        $this->Cell(30,8,'Date',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(30,8,'CTC No.',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(60,8,'Name',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(23,8,'Individual',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(23,8,'Corporation',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(24,8,'Total',1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
    }
    function viewTable($db){
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $repnumber=$_POST['id'];
        $stmt = $db->query("select * from tblctcab where cedrepnum='$repnumber' and username='$name' order by repdate asc");
        $count=0;
        while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $this->Cell(30,8,$data->repdate,1,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(30,8,$data->ctcnumber,1,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(60,8,$data->cedlname.', '.$data->cedfname,1,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(23,8,$data->totalampa,1,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(23,8,'',1,0,'C');
            $this->Cell(24,8,$data->totalampa,1,0,'C');
            $this->Ln();
            }
        $stmts = $db->query("select * from tblctcc where cedrepn='$repnumber' and username='$name' order by rpdate asc");
        $count=0;
        while($dat = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $this->Cell(30,8,$dat->rpdate,1,0,'C');
                $this->Cell(30,8,$dat->ctcnum,1,0,'C');
                $this->Cell(60,8,$dat->comfname,1,0,'C');
                $this->Cell(23,8,'',1,0,'C');
                $this->Cell(23,8,$dat->totalampas,1,0,'C');
                $this->Cell(24,8,$dat->totalampas,1,0,'C');
                $this->Ln();
             }
        $dbs=new mysqli('localhost' , 'root' , '', 'tres');
        $repdate=$_POST['id'];
        $ctcab = $dbs->query("select sum(totalampa) as totalampa from tblctcab where cedrepnum='$repnumber'  and username='$name'");
        $data = $ctcab->fetch_assoc();
        $totalab = $data['totalampa'];
        $ctcc = $dbs->query("select sum(totalampas) as totalampas from tblctcc where cedrepn='$repnumber' and username='$name'");
        $datac = $ctcc->fetch_assoc();
        $totalcc = $datac['totalampas'];
        $overall = $totalab + $totalcc;

        $this->SetTextColor(136,0,0);
        $this->SetFont('Times','B',10);
        $this->Cell(120,8,$_POST['id'],1,0,'C');
        //$this->Cell(55,8,'TOTAL',1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(23,8,number_format($totalab),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(23,8,number_format($totalcc),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(24,8,number_format($totalab),1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();

        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
        $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
        $this->Cell(95,8,'',0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(95,8,'',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->Cell(95,5,'Prepared By:',0,0,'L');
        $this->Cell(95,5,' Certified By:',0,0,'L');
        $this->Ln();

        $this->SetFont('Times','',10);
        $this->Cell(95,5,$_SESSION['name'],0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(95,5,'CONNIE',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->Cell(95,5,$_SESSION['position'],0,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(95,5,'Treasurer',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln();
    }
    function footer(){
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'R');
    }

}
$pdf = new myPDF();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();

$pdf->AddPage('','A4',0);

$pdf->headerTable();

$pdf->viewTable($db);

$pdf->Output();
```